# How to get specific RequestSecurityToken serialization

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ws-federation, ws-trust

I'm new to WCF, .NET, web services and everything -  in fact, I was mainly a java & SQL coder until I took on my current job.

The task at hand: Portions of our customers' data in our database needs to be exported regularly to a database that is provided by a third party and accessible through a web service, which in turn is federation-secured with an STS provided by a fourth party.

After hours spent with confusing MSDN documentation and tons of blog posts on WCF, I still can't get the STS to talk to me, all I get is a `(400) Bad Request.`.

My code:

```
private static SecurityToken RequestSecurityToken()
{
    WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
    binding.AllowCookies = true;
    WSHttpSecurity security = new WSHttpSecurity();
    security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
    security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
    security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
    security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
    binding.Security = security;
    WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, "https://FOURTH_PARTY_STS");
    factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
    factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.TrustedPeople, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "CUSTOMER_CERTIFICATE");
    RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
        AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("https://THIRD_PARTY_WS"),                
        TokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0"
    };
    rst.Claims.Dialect = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706/authclaims"; // Taken from an exception message 
    rst.Claims.Add(new RequestClaim("urn:tgic:names:ISTS:1.0:user:PartnerId", false, "CUSTOMER_ID"));
    return factory.CreateChannel().Issue(rst);
}
```

produces this SOAP body:

```
<trust:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
    <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <wsa:Address>https://THIRD_PARTY_WS</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:EndpointReference>
    </wsp:AppliesTo>
    <trust:Claims Dialect="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706/authclaims" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:ClaimType Uri="urn:tgic:names:ISTS:1.0:user:PartnerId" Optional="true">
            <auth:Value>CUSTOMER_ID</auth:Value>
        </auth:ClaimType>
    </trust:Claims>
    <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
    <trust:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0</trust:TokenType>
</trust:RequestSecurityToken>
```

According to the fourth party's documentation, the STS expects something like this:

```
<wst:RequestSecurityToken 
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
    xmlns:wsp15="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" 
    xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512" 
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
    Context="1aae57c8-092c-47a4-a5eb-c2ecbc21441d"> 
    <wst:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0</wst:TokenType>
    <wst:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</wst:RequestType>
    <wsp:AppliesTo>
        <wsp15:URI>https://THIRD_PARTY_WS</wsp15:URI>
    </wsp:AppliesTo>
    <wst:Claims Dialect="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:AttributeStatementType"> 
        <saml2:AttributeStatement xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
            <saml2:Attribute Name="urn:tgic:names:ISTS:1.0:user:PartnerId" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
                <saml2:AttributeValue>9330931615</saml2:AttributeValue>
            </saml2:Attribute>
        </saml2:AttributeStatement> 
    </wst:Claims>
    <wst:Lifetime>
        <wsu:Created>2013-09-17T18:18:10Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2013-09-17T18:23:10Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wst:Lifetime>
</wst:RequestSecurityToken>
```

Somewhere else in that documentation it's stated that Context and Lifetime are optional. Therefore, as far as I can see, I have two issues:

1. How do I get the AppliesTo address to be serialized as URI element?
2. How do I get the Claims to be serialized as Attribute/AttributeValue elements (with correct dialect)?

Do I have to implement some custom serialization? If so, how and where do I hook it into the factory/binding/request?

Answer (score 0):

1. To work with STS you have to use WS2007HttpBinding instead of WSHttpBinding. You can find STS example in WIF SDK. It contain an example with custom token. Look [here](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=4451)
2. Try issue securitytoken without additional client parameters. Make a working solution that just issue token and call RP method.
3. As far as I understand you want pass to STS custom client credential **PartnerId**. In my project I'm using passing custom credentials through the request's **AdditionalContext**.

rst.AdditionalContext = new AdditionalContext();
rst.AdditionalContext.Items.Add(new ContextItem(new Uri("you_any_uri"), PartnerId));

This way does not require any serializers.

Another way to pass client credentials's: using [RequestSecurityToken.Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.protocols.wstrust.requestsecuritytoken(v=vs.110).aspx). In this case you must implement a custom request serializer.

```
var channelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binging, endpoint)
{
       TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13
};
channelFactory.WSTrustRequestSerializer = CustomRequestSerializer;
```

Here implementation of custom [WSTrust13RequestSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.wstrust.wstrust13requestserializer.aspx)

```
public class CustomRequestSerializer: WSTrust13RequestSerializer
{
    public override void WriteXmlElement(XmlWriter writer, string elementName, object elementValue, RequestSecurityToken rst,
        WSTrustSerializationContext context)
    {
        var parameters = new string[1] {"paramname"};

        if (parameters.Any(p => p == elementName))
        {
            writer.WriteElementString(elementName, (string)elementValue);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WriteXmlElement(writer, elementName, elementValue, rst, context);
        }
    }

    public override void ReadXmlElement(XmlReader reader, RequestSecurityToken rst, WSTrustSerializationContext context)
    {
        var parameters = new string[1] {"paramname"};

        var key = parameters.FirstOrDefault(reader.IsStartElement);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            rst.Properties.Add(key, reader.ReadElementContentAsString());
            return;
        }

        base.ReadXmlElement(reader, rst, context);            
    }
}
```